# Como limpiar la cahe en Asp.Net Mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, webpack, cache

Tengo una aplicación hecha en Asp.Net mvc5 y cada vez que hago un cambio, en mis archivos css o js ,tengo que ir a limpiar la cache del navegador manualmente, como desarrollador no hay problema, el problema esta cuando esta la aplicación en producción, no le puedo estar diciendo a los usuarios que hagan lo mismo.

Comment: es que no deberia necesitar que el usuario limpi cache, por se supone que no pones cambios constantemente en produccion, con lo cual si actualizas solo detectara los cambios. O sea es correcto que el cliente tenga el cache para hacer la carga mas rapida, no lo inhabilites en produccion

Comment: la aplicación saldrá a producción en un 80% terminada, luego se irán haciendo cambios y corrigiendo bugs.

Comment: Las aplicaciones nunca están terminadas, siempre hay algún cambio en el contenido.  Uno no termina un sistema, solo lo abandona. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una manera muy común es utilizando un parámetro en la url del archivo

```
<script src="/scripts/archivo.js?v=1"></script>
```

En la parte final de la url se agrega un *querystring*, cuando hagas un despliegue ahora lo que tendrías que hacer es cambiar el número (cualquier número o texto funciona), de esta manera aprovechas el cache y cuando despliegues una nueva versión los usuarios no tendrán que limpiar manualmente el suyo, simplemente recargar la página.

---

Esa es la estrategia básica, pero si usas la característica de [**unión y minificación**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) de ASP.NET MVC, el framework maneja el parámetro automáticamente por tí:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
           .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // el resto de tus scripts...

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
 }
```

`EnableOptimizations` es lo que hace que se agregue el parámetro, el framework calcula el hash del archivo, así cuando el contenido cambia, cambia el parámetro.  En la vista los incluyes así por ejemplo:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

La plantilla por defecto de MVC5 incluye el ejemplo de cómo usar esta característica del framework, puedes revisar ahí.